# Why does router.query return an empty object in NextJS on first render?

Tags: javascript, next.js

My url is: http://localhost:3000/company/60050bd166cb770942b1dadd

I want to get the value of the id by using router.query. However when I console log router.query, it returns an empty object first and then return the object with data. This results in bugs in other parts of my code as I need the value of the id to fetch other data.

[image: Console log]

This is my code:

```
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';
import styles from './CompanyId.module.css';

import { useQuery } from '@apollo/client';
import { COMPANY_DETAILS } from '../../queries/company';

const CompanyDetails = () => {
  const router = useRouter();
  console.log(router.query);

  const { loading, data } = useQuery(COMPANY_DETAILS, {
    variables: { _id: companyId },
  });

  return (
    <div className={styles.container}>
      {loading ? <h1>Loading</h1> : <h1>{data.company.name}</h1>}
    </div>
  );
};

export default CompanyDetails;
```

My program is crashing right now because the companyId variable is empty on the first render. Is there anyway to go around this problem?

Comment: Try to wrap your your fetch function inside `usetEffect` and use `useLazyQuery` instead, and then update the state with `useState`

Comment: @Nico thank you for your input, I tried it with useLazyQuery along with useEffect and it works :)

Comment: If anyone else with `next@12.3.0` is experiencing this issue and is unable to fix it, upgrading to `next@12.3.1` resolved the issue for me.

Answer (score 4):

In Next.js:

- Pages that are statically optimized by [**Automatic Static Optimization**](https://nextjs.org/docs/routing/dynamic-routes#caveats) will be hydrated without their route parameters provided, i.e `query` will be an empty object `({})`.
- After hydration, Next.js will trigger an update to your application to provide the route parameters in the `query` object.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by using useLazyQuery instead of useQuery, and wrapped the function inside useEffect.

The problem was that NextJS's router.query returns an empty object on the first render and the actual object containing the query comes in at the second render.

This code works:

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';
import styles from './CompanyId.module.css';

import { useLazyQuery } from '@apollo/client';
import { COMPANY_DETAILS } from '../../queries/company';

const CompanyDetails = () => {
  const router = useRouter();

  const [getCompany, { loading, data }] = useLazyQuery(COMPANY_DETAILS);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (router.query.companyId) {
      getCompany({ variables: { _id: router.query.companyId } });
    }
  }, [router.query]);

  if (loading) return <h1>Loading....</h1>;

  return (
    <div className={styles.container}>
      {data && <h1>{data.company.name}</h1>}
    </div>
  );
};

export default CompanyDetails;
```

Comment: Using `router.query` here doesn't seem optimal as it changes multiple times on re-renders. So you would have the `useEffect` execute infinitely. 

`router.isReady` is the appropriate variable to use as it is a boolean and changes only one post page hydration.

Comment: Agree with @Paschal I think it's better to read the query directly from window.location intead. `const getQueryParams = () =>
  isServer() ? new URLSearchParams({}) : new URL(window.location.href).searchParams`